# Retrieve database from firebase in a listview

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-listview

I want to retrieve data from firebase in a listview but I am getting a blank output.

[image: This is a snapshot of my realtime database]

**below is the code**

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search__profile);
        user=new User();
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.searchlist);
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
      mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
//        databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();

        arrayList=new ArrayList<>();


databaseReference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(mAuth.getUid());

        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                arrayList.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    user=ds.getValue(User.class);

                    if (user != null) {
                        arrayList.add(user.First_name);
                    }
                    if (user != null) {
                        arrayList.add(user.Fathers_name);
                    }

                }
                arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(Search_Profile.this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1);
                listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });}}
```

what is the problem with it?

Comment: why you retrieving the single value and adding into the arraylist ?

Comment: i am having one more user created in database and these users are authenticated

Comment: the above code you have used will only provide you the recent user data

Comment: but i am getting only the blank output

Comment: can you post the full screenshot of what is another node under all ?

Comment: it is same as the first node just the details are different

Answer (score 0):

use this piece of code to retrieve your data.

```
databaseReference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(mAuth.getUid());

        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                arrayList.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                  for(DataSnapshot ds1:ds.getChildren())
                  {
                    user=ds1.getValue(User.class);

                    if (user != null) {
                        arrayList.add(user.First_name);
                        arrayList.add(user.Fathers_name);
                    }

                    arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(Search_Profile.this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1);
                    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                  }
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: i used your piece of code but my app is moving to the last page

Comment: i don't understand what you are saying